# How do I create 3 types of objects(movie, book & journal) from this text file and then display it?

Tags: c++

So far I can only create one type of object - books, can someone explain how can I create movie and journal objects?
This is what I have done so far:

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;

    struct Item {
      string type;
      string id;
      string title;
      string year;
    };

    struct Movie : Item {
      string director;
    };

    struct Book : public Item {
      string author;
      string pages;
    };

    struct Journal : public Item {
      string volume;
      string number;
    };

    void readBooks(ifstream& input, vector<Book>& books)
    {
      string line;
      while(getline(input, line)) {
        istringstream iss(line);
        Book book;
        getline(iss, book.type, ',');
        getline(iss, book.id, ',');
        getline(iss, book.title, ',');
        getline(iss, book.year, ',');
        getline(iss, book.author, ',');
        getline(iss, book.pages, ',');
        books.push_back(book);
        cout << "Type: " << book.type << endl;
        cout << "ID: " << book.id << endl;
        cout << "Title: " << book.title << endl;
        cout << "Year: " << book.year << endl;
        cout << "Author: " << book.author << endl;
        cout << "Number of Pages: " << book.pages << endl << endl;
    }
    }

    int main() {
    
    vector<Book> books;
    ifstream input("/Users/nethmi/Desktop/library.txt");
    if(input.is_open()){
        readBooks(input, books);
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

This the output I get:
[image]

### And this is the data in the text file:

Movie,200,Remember The Alamo,1945,George Smith

Movie,203,Lord of the ring: the fellowship of the ring,2001,Pete Jackson

Movie,206,Lord of the ring: the two towers,2002,Peter Jackson

Movie,210,Going for the Touchdown,1984,Frank Madden

Movie,211,Martian Hairdresser,1992,Debbie Gold

Book,231,How to Make Money,1987,Phil Barton,324

Book,240,Garden Projects At Home,1998,Mary Freeman,164

Book,202,The Haunted House Mystery,1996,Bert Morgan,53

Journal,207,ACM,2009,6,8

Journal,212,ACM,2010,5,8

Journal,215,J of Logic,2008,23,14

Journal,281,J of AI,2009,35,1

---

I deleted the movie and journal data to check if it works (just for the book object) and it does, but I don't know how to create 3 types of objects.

Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "readBooks" function opens the input file and parses each line with the assumption that it contains book data.   It needs to instead grab each line, then (based on your file format) examine the substring from the beginning of the line till the first comma  and compare it to values (MOVIE, BOOK, JOURNAL).  Once you know what kind of line it is, then pass the line into a function that is specific to creating the type of object needed by that line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Item
{
  string type;
  string id;
  string title;
  string year;
};

struct Movie : Item
{
  string director;
};

struct Book : public Item
{
  string author;
  string pages;
};

struct Journal : public Item
{
  string volume;
  string number;
};

void readLines(ifstream& input,
               vector<Book>& books,
               vector<Movie>& movies,
               vector<Journal>& journals)
{
  string line;
  while(getline(input, line)) {
    size_t firstCommaPos = line.find_first_of(',');
    string lineType = line.substr(0,firstCommaPos);
    istringstream iss(line);
    if(lineType.compare(std::string{"Book"}) == 0)
    {
        Book book;
        getline(iss, book.type, ',');
        getline(iss, book.id, ',');
        getline(iss, book.title, ',');
        getline(iss, book.year, ',');
        getline(iss, book.author, ',');
        getline(iss, book.pages, ',');
        books.push_back(book);
        cout << "Type: " << book.type << endl;
        cout << "ID: " << book.id << endl;
        cout << "Title: " << book.title << endl;
        cout << "Year: " << book.year << endl;
        cout << "Author: " << book.author << endl;
        cout << "Number of Pages: " << book.pages << endl << endl;
    }
    else if(lineType.compare(std::string{"Movie"}) == 0)
    {
        Movie movie;
        getline(iss, movie.type, ',');
        getline(iss, movie.id, ',');
        getline(iss, movie.title, ',');
        getline(iss, movie.year, ',');
        getline(iss, movie.director, ',');
        movies.push_back(movie);
        cout << "Type: " << movie.type << endl;
        cout << "ID: " << movie.id << endl;
        cout << "Title: " << movie.title << endl;
        cout << "Year: " << movie.year << director
        cout << "Director: " movie.director << endl << endl;
    }
    else if(lineType.compare(std::string{"Journal"}) == 0)
    {
        Journal journal;
        getline(iss, journal.type, ',');
        getline(iss, journal.id, ',');
        getline(iss, journal.title, ',');
        getline(iss, journal.year, ',');
        getline(iss, journal.volume, ',');
        getline(iss, journal.number, ',');
        journals.push_back(journal);
        cout << "Type: " << journal.type << endl;
        cout << "ID: " << journal.id << endl;
        cout << "Title: " << journal.title << endl;
        cout << "Year: " << journal.year << endl;
        cout << "Volume: " << journal.volume << endl;
        cout << "Number: " << journal.number << endl << endl;
    }   
}

int main()
{
    vector<Book> books;
    vector<Movie> movies;
    vector<Journal> journals;
    ifstream input("/Users/nethmi/Desktop/library.txt");
    if(input.is_open())
    {
        readLines(input, books, movies, journals);
    }

    return 0;
}
```